# DATEADD conditon take long time in SQL Server 2008 .Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to get data between previous month and current month in my sale table. I use the `dateadd` function to get month. But the query take long time to return result. When I remove date range in where clause, execution time is very fast. How can I add date range for month to fast execution time in query?

Here is my query.

```
select *
from sales S
where S.DOCUMENT_DATE >= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE())-1 , 0) and  
      S.DOCUMENT_DATE <= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE())+1 , -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your query, you want an index on `sales(document_date)`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff ,no effect on long execution time, still take long time

Comment: @dragullar . . . That is probably due to the volume of data being returned.  However, it shouldn't be slower for one month than for all months.  Another possibility is to create a *clustered* index on `document_date`.  Perhaps the issue is the time to the first row, so it only seems that returning all the data is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Nonclustered Index.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NC_IX_Sales_DOCUMENT_DATE ON Sales (DOCUMENT_DATE)
```

Then you could run your query.

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales s
WHERE s.DOCUMENT_DATE >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE())),0)
  AND s.DOCUMENT_DATE <= DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(m,0,getdate())+1, 0))
```

Also you could take in account that current month has not ended yet.

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales s
WHERE s.DOCUMENT_DATE >= DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())),0)
  AND s.DOCUMENT_DATE <= GETDATE()
```

Comment: if your query is so simple in real life,then no doubts create index on date column.don't forget to to remove *,and mention columnname.Secondly you can take two variable like "@FromDate" and "@Todate".And compare the performance.Don't forget to share your experience.

Comment: @ JCA ,no effect on long execution time, still take long time